# Restricting model parameters in cumulative logit model (or any ordinal model)

Tags: nonlinear-regression, constrained-regression

Imagine a model where the linear predictor of the cumulative response probabilities are equal to:

$$y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_1z_1 + b_4x_2z_1$$

Where $x_1$ and $x_2$ represent a 3 level categorical independent variable, and $z_1$ represents a dummy variable. $y$ is a 4 level ordinal outcome variable. I want $\dfrac{b_3}{b_1}$ to be equal to $\dfrac{b_4}{b_2}$. Is there a way to use GLM but specify this constraint?

Answer (score 2):

If the intercepts/thresholds should also change by the same factor, one can accomodate this is in a heteroscedastic model.

The usual motivation for a cumulative logit or probit model is that there is a latent logistic or normal variable $y^*$ with mean $\mu$ and constant variance (because the absolute scale is not identified):
$$
\begin{align}
  y^* & = \mathcal{L}(\mu, \sigma) \\
  \mu & = x^\top \beta \\
  \sigma & = 1
\end{align}
$$
And the observed variable $y$ then codes into which interval $(\alpha_{j-1}, \alpha_j)$ the latent variable falls. Consequently, the cumulative probability up to category $j$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathrm{Prob}(y ~\le~ j ~|~ x)
    & = \mathrm{Prob}(y^* ~\le~ \alpha_j ~|~ x) \\
    & = \Lambda(\alpha_j - x^\top \beta).
\end{align}
$$
And although the absolute scale is not identified, it is possible identify scale *differences*. In the equation above one can replace
$$
\begin{align}
  \log(\sigma) & = z^\top \gamma
\end{align}
$$
where $z$ must not contain an intercept for identifiability. In your case you would have $z \in \{0, 1\}$ and consequently $\sigma_0 = 1$ and $\sigma_1 = \exp(\gamma)$. The cumulative probability would be as above for group $z = 0$. And for $z = 1$ we would have
$$
\begin{align}
  \Lambda\left(\frac{\alpha_j ~-~ x^\top \beta}{\exp(\gamma)}\right)
    & = \Lambda(\alpha_j^* - x^\top \beta^*)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, this is a cumulative logit model as above but with $\alpha_j^* = \alpha_j/\exp(\gamma)$ and $\beta^* = \beta/\exp(\gamma)$.

Consequently, all slopes just differ by a multiplicative factor between the two groups: $\beta / \beta^* = \exp(\gamma)$. The same holds for the intercepts/thresholds $\alpha / \alpha^* = \exp(\gamma)$.

In R, this kind of cumulative link models can be fitted with function `clm()` from package `ordinal`. Furthermore, the `glmx` package provides function `hetglm()` that can fit GLMs with such a heteroscedastic scaling term.

Comment: Dear Achim, Thank you for this answer. Perhaps I have misunderstood. What I meant is that the linear predictor of the cumulative response probabilities are equal to b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b3*x1*z1 + b4*x2*z1. What I then wanted is to specify constraints on the relationships between the regression beta coefficients (specifically that b4 devided by b2 is equal to b3 devided by b1). This constraints should apply at every level of Y.

Comment: My problem with exactly understanding your question was the specification of the intercept. There is not _one intercept_ b0 but instead there are _three thresholds_ for four response categories ($\alpha_j$ in my notation). And the heteroscedastic term scales all of these coefficients in the model (including the slopes). For the binary probit case, the following conference slides might help to understand the motication and potential problems of this model: https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/ERCIM-2013.pdf